# How do I return a POST request and a view in the same controller, in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route in my Laravel application. You get sent there after submitting a registration form.

```php
Route::get('/discnotify', 'App\Http\Controllers\DiscordNotify@notification')->name('discnotify');
```

It essentially sends a POST request to a Discord webhook, so I can be notified on Discord when a user registers. Here's the controller that does that:

```php
public function notification()
{
    return Http::post('https://discord.com/api/webhooks/840070960463872020/MVPj3cYUbs8AbeI8XZMHeu9MPXVqaPt4WWlG2Y9UGS7lZv-vzNA-ES1d4QUa119HbxDQ', [
        'content' => "A new user has registered.",
        'embeds' => [
            [
                'title' => Auth()->user()->name,
                'description' => "To be added.",
                'color' => '4548285',
            ]
        ],
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('register');
}
```

The problem is that when a user registers and gets sent to that route, it works, but they're left with a blank screen. As you can see, I attempted to redirect at the end, but apparently, I cannot do this when there's already a return function before it. Putting it before the POST request just returns the view and doesn't send the request, etc.

How can I send this request AND redirect the user to a view at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the first return. `Http::post(...)` sends the request. You don't need a return statement for it to work.

```php
public function notification()
{
    Http::post(...)

    return redirect()->route('register');
}
```

However, if you want some error management, you could use the request's response.

```php
public function notification()
{
    $response = Http::post(...);

    if ($response->status() !== 200) { // or whatever http status code discord is supposed to return
        return back()->with('error', "Discord request returned status {$response->status()}.");
    }

    return redirect()->route('register');
}
```